# Passthrough AMD GPU to virtual machine without using second GPU

Tags: gpu, virtualization

I read some topics about passing GPU to virtual machine, but that examples requires an two GPU's (one for VM and one for host OS). And now I find mentions about passing single available in system GPU to VM. Does this possible in Ubuntu and how I gonna do that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to pass one and single GPU on the host hardware to guest OS, but it requires host OS to not use that GPU - host OS will have no GUI in this case. I found a lot easier to borrow old Nvidia GPU for host OS…

Comment: This doesn't answer your own question how to achieve this feat. I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)